# Wavelet time extraction

Tags: wavelet, python

I am trying to understand one simple thing in wavelets and I searched a lot, but did not get any idea.

I need to perform Multilevel 1-D wavelet decomposition on my signal. I have arrays

```
signal[] and time[]
```

( time[x] corresponds to the time at which signal[x] occurs ) . After I perform

```
wavedec(signal,level=1,'wname'))
```

I need to plot cA1 vs the time signal. But how do I know which time points should I select. If i change the 'wname' , I get different length cA1.

For example, for a signal of length 9285, when I do

```
[cA1,cD1]=pywt.wavedec(signal,db1, level=1,mode=pywt.MODES.zpd)
length of cA1=4643

[cA1,cD1]=pywt.wavedec(signal,db2, level=1,mode=pywt.MODES.zpd)
length of cA1 = 4644
```

How can we determine the variation of cA1 and how can we select the corresponding time. I use pywavelet

Comment: I think I got the answer. We should reconstruct using upcoef. But I am not very sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the arrays you get back depends on the [mode](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/signal-extension-modes.html#ref-modes) you use to do the decomposition and the wavelet length, which can vary like you see between db1 and db2:

```
len(cA) == len(cD) == floor((len(data) + wavelet.dec_len - 1) / 2)
```

If you switch to periodization mode `mode='per'`, you get a different calculation that may be more consistent for you:

```
len(cA) == len(cD) == ceil(len(data) / 2)
```

Regardless, decomposition is generally dyadic, so your dyad width is `len(signal)/len(cAn)`.

Once you go muiltilevel (use level='2', etc.), you'll have small variations in length as well. To account for this, use [IDWT](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/idwt-inverse-discrete-wavelet-transform.html) to reconstruct.